# Subtraction of Probability Measures

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

I have just read that apparently the following two conditions are equivalent:
$$ \int f dP \geq \int f dQ \Longleftrightarrow \int f d(P-Q) \geq 0$$
for $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $P$ and $Q$ two probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Maybe I am missing some measure theory here but I can not see why this is true without further assumptions.

Comment: Well, presumably you need the assumption that all three integrals exist.

Comment: Assuming the existence of integrals, use Lebesgue integration definition.

Comment: Very intuitively, if $P', Q'$ exist you said $$\int f P' dx \geq \int f Q' dx \leftrightarrow \int f (P-Q)' dx \geq 0$$ which is true...

Comment: That was my intuition too but this only works if both measures are absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\lambda$, which is no assumed.